# Firefox Tree Style Tab - How to close a tree in one click?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

The [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) is great. But one thing I would like to do is to close the whole tree in one click, e.g. just by clicking the middle key of my mouse on the parent tab of the tree. Is that doable? To right click then left click is still a kind of too much for me.

Comment: There's a setting for this, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I get it... When the tree is *collapsed* I can close it with one click. Didn't explore enough!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to Tree Style Tab that adds the behavior you want - middle  clicking on the cross closes a the whole tree (whether it is collapsed or not). Its called "TST Change Close Tab Button Behavior".

1. Install Tree Style Tab extension (only if you haven't already!)
2. Install "TST Change Close Tab Button Behavior" extension from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tst-change-close-tab-button-be/
3. Allow permission in Tree Style Tab extension Options -> "Extra Features via Other Addons"